# Error when using 'winexe' tool. Trying to invoke Windows commands via Linux server

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, samba

Successfully installed winexe tool([link](http://steronius.blogspot.com/2013/05/psexec-via-linux.html)) but when executing the tool, the following command appears

```
#./winexe -U 'domain\user%pass' //ip "tasklist /V"
ERROR: Failed to open connection - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Any help? Found similar question in stack, but no answer. 
Open for any other easy suggestions on how to invoke Windows commands via Linux server, preference from PowerShell.

Comment: Have you checked all the prerequisites as described in your [link1](https://web.archive.org/web/20131115153937/http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-could-not-start_topic3698_post11962.html) and [link2](http://jamesrayanderson.blogspot.com/2010/04/psexec-and-ports.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Your winexe is probably using SMB1 dialect to connect, which is deprecated in modern windows versions.

Just for debugging purposes, temporarily enable SMB1 in Windows (hint:OptionalFeatures.exe) and try again. It should work, unless you also need to add "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy" to the registry.

Don't forget to disable SMB1 again.

There is a winexec binary with SMB2 support that works in Centos 7 against Windows 10:
http://dl-openaudit.opmantek.com/winexe-static

The source code that worked for me:
https://bitbucket.org/reevertcode/reevert-winexe-waf

Besides the README file, you should also read the 'BUILD' file, it contains additional information (patches to apply).

Good luck!

Comment: hi masimito, download for winexec binary with smb2 support is not available... do you still have it somewhere?

Comment: hello @Asmerito, I do have a static winexec binary againts current Centos 7 in my drive, but you should consider compiling it yourself:

https://bitbucket.org/reevertcode/reevert-winexe-waf/src/master/

In case you want to try this binary in a safe environment, you can get it from here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zFeMH422KQQRTSl8mjAzGS-hPwjJUJTi/view?usp=sharing